# Sequential Quadratic Programming in R to find optimal weights of an Equally-Weighted Risk Contribution Portfolio

Tags: r, finance, portfolio, quantitative-finance

### Introduction to the problem

I am trying to write down a code in R so to obtain the weights of an Equally-Weighted Contribution (ERC) Portfolio. As some of you may know, the portfolio construction was presented by [Maillard, Roncalli and Teiletche](http://thierry-roncalli.com/download/erc.pdf).

Skipping technicalities, in order to find the optimal weights of an ERC portfolio one needs to solve the following Sequential Quadratic Programming problem:

[image]

with:

[image]
[image]

Suppose we are analysing *N* assets. In the above formulas, we have that *x* is a (N x 1) vector of portfolio weights and Σ is the (N x N) variance-covariance matrix of asset returns.

### What I have done so far

Using the function [slsqp](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nloptr/versions/1.0.4/topics/slsqp) of the package [nloptr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/) which solves SQP problems, I would like to solve the above minimisation problem. Here is my code. Firstly, the objective function to be minimised:

```
ObjFuncERC <- function (x, Sigma) {
sum <- 0
R <- Sigma %*% x
    for (i in 1:N) {
        for (j in 1:N) {
            sum <- sum + (x[i]*R[i] - x[j]*R[j])^2
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, the starting point (we start by an equally-weighted portfolio):

```
x0 <- matrix(1/N, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
```

Then, the equality constraint (weights must sum to one, that is: sum of the weights minus one equal zero):

```
heqERC <- function (x) {
    h <- numeric(1)
    h[1] <- (t(matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = 1)) %*% x) - 1
    return(h)
}
```

Finally, the lower and upper bounds constraints (weights cannot exceed one and cannot be lower than zero):

```
lowerERC <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
upperERC <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
```

So that the function which should output optimal weights is:

```
slsqp(x0 = x0, fn = ObjFuncERC, Sigma = Sigma, lower = lowerERC, upper = upperERC, heq = heqERC)
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to share with you my variance-covariance matrix (which takes name Sigma and is a (29 x 29) matrix, so that N = 29) so to reproduce my result, still you can simulate one.

### The output error

Running the above code yields the following error:

```
Error in nl.grad(x, fn) : 
Function 'f' must be a univariate function of 2 variables.
```

I have no idea what to do guys. Probably, I have misunderstood how things must be written down in order for the function `slsqp` to understand what to do. *Can someone help me understand how to fix the problem and get the result I want?*

---

**UPDATE ONE**: as pointed out by @jogo in the comments, I have updated the code, but it still produces an error. The code and the error above are now updated.

---

**UPDATE 2**: as requested by @jaySf, here is the full code that allows you to reproduce my error.

```
## ERC Portfolio Test
# Preliminary Operations
rm(list=ls())
require(quantmod)
require(nloptr)

# Load Stock Data in R through Yahoo! Finance
stockData <- new.env()
start <- as.Date('2014-12-31')
end <- as.Date('2017-12-31')
tickers <-c('AAPL','AXP','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','DIS','GE','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','JPM','KO','MCD','MMM','MRK','MSFT','NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','UTX','V','VZ','WMT','XOM')
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, env = stockData, from = start, to = end, periodicity = 'monthly')

# Create a matrix containing the price of all assets
prices <- do.call(cbind,eapply(stockData, Op))
prices <- prices[-1, order(colnames(prices))]
colnames(prices) <- tickers

# Compute Returns
returns <- diff(prices)/lag(prices)[-1,]

# Compute variance-covariance matrix 
Sigma <- var(returns)
N <- 29

# Set up the minimization problem
ObjFuncERC <- function (x, Sigma) {
sum <- 0
R <- Sigma %*% x
    for (i in 1:N) {
        for (j in 1:N) {
            sum <- sum + (x[i]*R[i] - x[j]*R[j])^2
        }
    }
}


x0 <- matrix(1/N, nrow = N, ncol = 1)


heqERC <- function (x) {
    h <- numeric(1)
    h[1] <- t(matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = 1)) %*% x - 1
}

lowerERC <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
upperERC <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = 1)

slsqp(x0 = x0, fn = ObjFuncERC, Sigma = Sigma, lower = lowerERC, upper = upperERC, heq = heqERC)
```

Comment: According to the documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nloptr/versions/1.0.4/topics/slsqp `fn=` shoud be a function - not a call to a function. So eventually it should be: `slsqp(x0 = x0, fn = ObjFuncERC, Sigma = Sigma, ...)`

Comment: @jogo Good point! I have updated the code, but now it returns that `'f' must be a univariate function of 2 variables`. At this point, I'm starting to think that slsqp might not be the right function to solve my problem, but I have no clue on what should I use. The above is indeed a Sequential Quadratic Programming problem...

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the issue. Please check this in a fresh R session and add additional information accordingly (packages, variables..). Thanks.

Comment: If `Sigma` is constant you can define a function to construct your objective function: 
`defObj <-  function(Sigma) function(x) ObjFuncERC(x, Sigma);
myObj <- defOBJ(Sigma);
slsqp(x0 = x0, fn = myOBJ, ...)`

Comment: Your objective function seems to be equivalent with `function (x, Sigma) { R <- Sigma %*% x; xR <- x*R; sum(outer(FUN='-', xR, xR)^2) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted several mistakes in your code. For instance, `ObjFuncERC` is not returning any value. You should use the following instead:

```
# Set up the minimization problem
ObjFuncERC <- function (x, Sigma) {
  sum <- 0
  R <- Sigma %*% x
  for (i in 1:N) {
    for (j in 1:N) {
      sum <- sum + (x[i]*R[i] - x[j]*R[j])^2
    }
  }
  sum
}
```

`heqERC` doesn't return anything too, I also changed your function a bit

```
heqERC <- function (x) {
    sum(x) - 1
}
```

I made those changes and tried `slsqp` without `lower` and `upper` and it worked. Still, another thing to consider is that you set `lowerERC` and `upperERC` as matrices. Use the following instead:

```
lowerERC <- rep(0,N)
upperERC <- rep(1,N)
```

Hope this helps.